# No TabController for TabBar when adding bottom TabBar to AppBar (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar, tabbar

So what I'm trying to do, besides my app bar where I have logo and search option I want to add bottom TabBar where user can choose between movies or tv shows, and while he is on one of them the text should be lit up (different color). But when I tried to add the TabBar i got an error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(411.4, 683.4),
devicePixelRatio: 2.6, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding:
EdgeInsets.zero, viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, alwaysUse24HourFormat:
false, accessibleNavigation: false, highContrast: false, disableAnimations: false, invertColors:
false, boldText: false, navigationMode: traditional)):
No TabController for TabBar.
When creating a TabBar, you must either provide an explicit TabController using the "controller"
property, or you must ensure that there is a DefaultTabController above the TabBar.
In this case, there was neither an explicit controller nor a default controller.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  AppBar file:///C:/Users/Meliha/Desktop/Rubicon/chillax/lib/presenter/home_page_movies.dart:22:15

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _TabBarState._updateTabController.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/tabs.dart:965:9)
#1      _TabBarState._updateTabController (package:flutter/src/material/tabs.dart:974:6)
#2      _TabBarState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/material/tabs.dart:1006:5)
#3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4653:11)
#4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4469:5)
#5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3541:14)
#6      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6094:32)
...     Normal element mounting (99 frames)
#105    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3541:14)
#106    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6094:32)
...     Normal element mounting (238 frames)
#344    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3541:14)
#345    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6094:32)
...     Normal element mounting (300 frames)
#645    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3541:14)
#646    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3306:18)
#647    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1182:16)
#648    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1153:5)
#649    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1095:18)
#650    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2647:19)
#651    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1094:13)
#652    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:934:7)
#653    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:915:7)
(elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Here is the code of the main page for the movies:

```
import 'package:eva_icons_flutter/eva_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/view/now_playing_movie.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/view/now_playing_tv.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/view/test.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/view/top_movies.dart';
import 'package:movie_app/view/top_tvs.dart';
import '../style/style.dart';

class HomePageMovie extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePageMovie> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF151C26),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF151C26),
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SvgPicture.asset(
              logo,
              height: 195,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(
                EvaIcons.searchOutline,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
        ],
        bottom: TabBar(
            indicatorColor: Color(0xFFf4C10F),
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            indicatorWeight: 3.0,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.movie),
                text: "Movies",
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.tv),
                text: "TV Shows",
              )
            ]),
        titleSpacing: 0.0,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          NowPlayingMovies(),
          BestMovie(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any form of help/tip/guide would be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for your problem is right inside the error text

> When creating a TabBar, you must either provide an explicit TabController using the "controller"
> property, or you must ensure that there is a DefaultTabController above the TabBar.

Therefore the easiest solution is to wrap your `TabBar` with the `DefaultTabController`. Since you are making use of the `bottom` property of `AppBar` which expects a `PreferredSizeWidget`, you additionally need to wrap it all inside something that implements this (since it's an abstract class) - easiest solution here is to just make use of `PreferredSize`. Complete example could look like this:

```dart
AppBar(
  bottom: PreferredSize(
    // Set whatever size you want - this is a good default one
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
    child: DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: TabBar(
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            text: 'Movies',
          ),
          Tab(
            text: 'TV Shows',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

The error logs are pretty verbose at times, but this is the crucial message:

> When creating a TabBar, you must either provide an explicit TabController using the "controller"
> property, or you must ensure that there is a DefaultTabController above the TabBar.
> In this case, there was neither an explicit controller nor a default controller.

You just need to wrap your `Scaffold` widget in a `DefaultTabController` and give it a length corresponding to the number of tabs you have. For more complex behaviour you can initialise a `ScrollController` and add this to the `controller:` parameter of the `TabBar` and `TabBarView`.

I also notice in the example you have a `ListView` containing your two tab widgets. This won't work, swap it out for a `TabBarView`.

Comment: So how can I put 2 methods inside one tab bar, because here I have this situation: ´ body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: TabBarView(
            children:[buildPage1(), buildPage2()],
          ),
        ));
  }

  buildPage1() {
    NowPlayingMovies();
    BestMovie();
  }

  buildPage2() {
    NowPlayingTV();
    BestTV();
  } ´dand it displays error